# Jenkins job dynamic parameters and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, jenkins, jobs

I would like to explain my case first of all.
I have mongodb database with following data:

```
{
  {
    "name": "env1",
    "host": "hostname1"
  },
  {
    "name": "env2",
    "host": "hostname2"
  },
  {
    "name": "env3",
    "host": "hostname3"
  },
  {
    "name": "env4",
    "host": "hostname4"
  }
}
```

The number of environments increases from time to time.

Now, I need to develop a Jenkins job with parameter (may be **Active Choices Parameter**?) that by clicking in jenkins job **Buils with Parameters**, behind the sence it will connect to mongodb and will retrieve data in to populate it as values in job parameter, like in picture below.

[image]

What are the steps to do that?
In one of our jobs we fetching similar from elasticsearch using http url, but in mongodb is not possible(familiar with mongodb atlas) in our case.